# Convert the following 32 bit binary numbers represented in IEEE floating point (S, Fraction ,Exponent) to decimal number

Tags: floating-point, binary, ieee

**0**  00000000000000000000000  **0111011**

How would I do this problem I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bolding suggests that you might be a bit confused about the order of fields; IEEE generally uses the order [sign,exponent,fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) for floating point numbers. (Incidentally, this allows the use of twos-complement-integer sorts to sort IEEE floating point numbers, if there are no NaNs or other non-numeric values.)

So what are we looking at here? The first bit is the sign: 0. So we have a positive number. (How to remember this? Go back to the allowed-to-use-integer-sort -- a leading one in a twos-complement integer means it's negative.)

The next eight bits are the exponent: also 0. This is the lowest possible exponent value; it normally represents an unsigned integer biased by 127, or the value -127. However, the exponent value 0 is reserved for encoding subnormal numbers (numbers less than the smallest normally representable); in this special case, the effective exponent is -126, but rather than representing the number 1.fraction * 2^exponent, a subnormal represents the number 0.fraction * 2^exponent.

Finally, we have the fraction, which is `0000000000000000111011`. So our total number is 0.0000000000000000111011b * 2^-126. Converting this to decimal is left to the reader.

Comment: You can also check out [this site](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=0000003B), which I have no association with but seems accurate.

Comment: Two’s complement will not sort floating-point numbers in ascending order, because it orders the negative numbers in the reverse order. For example, as two’s complement, 0xbf800000 is less than 0xc0000000. As floating point with the common encoding, they are –1 and –2, respectively, and –1 is of course not less than –2.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @addaon's previously posted answer. In addition, the conversion can be done easily in some languages, including Java:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] unused) {
      int raw = 0b0000000000000000000000000111011;
      float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(raw);
      System.out.println(f);
   }
}
```

(You need version 7 to get the binary literal, but the same thing can be done a little less directly in earlier versions)

The output is 8.3E-44, consistent with interpretation as a positive denormalized number, and with the conversion web site.